# Get closest element between two dataframes - multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I am comparing.

I would like to get the closest matching item between two dataframes.

```
DF1

Item   Location   Fabric   Date produced

item1     Spain     AB2     11/01/2015
item2     France    ST1     25/04/2017


DF2

Alternative Item      Location    Fabric   Date produced

alternative_item1        Spain       AB6      15/01/2015
alternative_item2        Spain       AB2      25/05/2014
alternative_item3        Spain       AB2      11/03/2013
alternative_item4       France       ST1      25/04/2017
alternative_item5           UK       ST1      19/02/2020
alternative_item6        Italy       ST1      07/04/2012
```

Above, on DF1 I have 2 items and on DF2 I have the alternative items.
I am looking to get the closest matching pair between the two DFs, as below.

```
DF_Final

Item     Alternative Item

item1   alternative_item2     
item2   alternative_item4
```

item1 gets paired with alternative_item2, since their "Location" and "Fabric" is the same and the production dates are the closest (alternative_item3 is more distant timewise).

On the same way, item2 gets paired with alternative_item4 since this is the only alternative item that matches the "Location" and "Fabric" criteria.

What methods would you use in order to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge by `Location` and `Fabric`, then group by `Location`, `Fabric` and chose the minimal difference:

```
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Location', 'Fabric'])
out['diff'] = out['Date produced_x'] - out['Date produced_y']
out = out.iloc[out.groupby(['Location', 'Fabric'])['diff'].agg(lambda x: x.sort_values().head(1).index)][['Item', 'Alternative Item']]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    Item   Alternative Item
2  item2  alternative_item4
0  item1  alternative_item2
```

Comment: I have actually seen now that not all Items are getting paired with an alternative item, although all of them have an alternative one. Will try to add in here a more elaborated example df.

Comment: @Rodrigo It's better to create a new question here on SO - that way more people can look on it.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. What you did was perfect and this will certainly help other people! All I had to do was actually to adapt the columns used on the merge and the group by, to my specific case. I had to experiment with the different combinations to get exactly what I wanted. It was just that. Thank you!